# Reference to type 'Matrix4x4' claims it is defined in 'System.Numerics', but it could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am building a Unity project for Hololens 2 which is using the library `System.Numerics` from `.NET`

I imported this project from git as is, but I am getting several errors similar to:

```
System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 converted4x4LocationMatrix = ConvertRightHandedMatrix4x4ToLeftHanded(suObject.GetLocationAsMatrix());
error CS7069: Reference to type 'Matrix4x4' claims it is defined in 'System.Numerics', but it could not be found
```

`System.Numerics` seems to be missing as well `Vector3` and `Vector2` classes.

The project is a few years old, so probably the version of Unity which I am using needs to change something in the configuration to make it compatible with a 'System.Numerics' version where `Matrix4x4` would be present. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am using `Unity 2019.2.4f1` with `Windows Build Support IL2CPP`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `System.Numerics` instead of the Unity built-in types [`UnityEngine.Matrix4x4`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.html), [`UnityEngine.Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) etc?

Comment: Actually I took that project as an example of how to use Scene Understanding, and I was just trying to make it work as is. I will take your advice if I end up rewriting the project to adapt it to my needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems the error was due to the .Net version used in the project by default was the wrong one. I had to change it to 4.x, the steps were:

**Build Settings** -> **Player Settings** -> **Other Settings** -> **Api Compatibility Level** and select **.Net 4.x**

Comment: Addition: If you can not find the "Build Settings" you need to exit the safe-mode and then go into "File" -> "Build Settings". If you are in Safe-Mode (because compiler errors during startup of unity) that menu-point is missing.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework also works
(edit -> project settings -> player settings -> API compatibility level).

Tested for UWP builds with MRTK on Unity 2022.3.6f1, I had this error when using the scene awareness feature from the MRTK feature toolbox.